# How to search a string from list in python

Tags: python

I have python code:

```
bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
try:
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    contents = response['Body'].read()
    print(contents)
```

It will show result like:

```
D_REGION="east"

A_NAME="diet"

V_ID="44"

K_PASS="N/A"

TRIAL_PRODUCTION="TRIAL"
```

I want to validate this by checking if value is **TRIAL** or value is **PROD**
then print whole list otherwise it will fail.
How can we search a string in from a list using python?

Comment: Did you at least tried to solve the problem by yourself ? Oh and it has nothing to do with `lambda` not with http responses - it's plain string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> contents = '''D_REGION="east"
... 
... A_NAME="diet"
... 
... V_ID="44"
... 
... K_PASS="N/A"
... 
... TRIAL_PRODUCTION="TRIAL"'''
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'TRIAL_PRODUCTION="(TRIAL|PROD)"', contents).group(1)
'TRIAL'
```

Comment: You don't even need a regex for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> contents = """D_REGION="east"
... 
... A_NAME="diet"
... 
... V_ID="44"
... 
... K_PASS="N/A"
... 
... TRIAL_PRODUCTION="TRIAL"
... """
>>> # couldn't be much simpler:
>>> 'TRIAL_PRODUCTION="TRIAL"' in contents or 'TRIAL_PRODUCTION="PROD"' in contents
True
>>> # a bit more elegant
>>> any(target in contents for target in ('TRIAL_PRODUCTION="TRIAL"', 'TRIAL_PRODUCTION="PROD"'))
True
```

Now what about learning Python (at least the most basic things) before you try to use it ?

Comment: I think OP wants to know which of the two values it is, not just if it's one or the other.

Comment: "I want to validate this by checking if value is TRIAL or value is PROD then print whole list" => I understand this as "if value is TRIAL _or_ value is PROD then proceed else fail". But looking for one specific value is even more trivial and still doesn't need a regex.